# Why does image dimension comparison give wrong result in Django?

Tags: django, image, upload, dimension

I have the following code for image upload:

**models.py**

```
class Item(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/item_images', height_field='height', width_field='width')
```

**template**

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.image }}
        {% if item.height > item.width %}
            {% widthratio item.width item.height 250 as width %}
            <li><img src="{{ item.image }}" height="250" width="{{ width }}"/>H: {{ item.height }} W: {{ item.width }} Height: 250 Width: {{ width }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I want this to show images whose height is greater than the width. However I uploaded an image with height: 956 and width: 1796. This image is not supposed to show. But it does! On the other hand, I uploaded an image with height much greater than width but it doesn't show. If I am not wrong, Django understands height as the Y-axis right? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: are you saving the values of height and width correctly?

Comment: Yes. I have checked properties of the files.

Comment: Can it be that the horizontal measure is the height and the vertical measure is the width?

Comment: I dont think that django takes wrong names for x-y coordinates